# Smarty outputs blank page

Tags: php, smarty

**SOLVED: Error in template file**

I have Smarty setup like this:

```
require_once 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->compile_dir = $compile_dir;
$smarty->template_dir = $tpl_dir;
```

That's all I should need for now... I have Smarty setup exactly like this for another site and it works just fine on the same server.

`var_dump($smarty)` outputs all its public variables and `$smarty->template_exists("index.tpl")` returns `1`, which would both indicate that Smarty is properly setup and working, however, both `$smarty->display("index.tpl")` and `$output = $smarty->fetch("index.tpl"); echo $output;` outputs blank page. And the index.tpl file certainly contains HTML.

Have I forgotten some step or what?

Edit:

Added

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL + E_NOTICE);
```

Also created config directory for Smarty.

And tried `$output = $smarty->fetch("index.tpl"); var_dump($output)`.

Still blank page.

If I `echo "foo";` before `$smarty->display("index.tpl")` it outputs the line, but if I do it after it, it doesn't output it.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($output)`?

Comment: And have you got errors showing? If there's an error on the page and errors are off then it just won't output anything.

Comment: Hi - you should add the solution you found as an answer rather than just saying its solved.  Might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had additional `{foo.bar}` (without `$`) variables in the template file that were supposed to be implemented later in the code, assuming Smarty would just replace those with blank I didn't think it could be those causing the problem, but after removing them it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I had a similar issue. Turned out that the template contained something like `{$foo="$obj->value"}`. Turned out that interpolating this did not work

Comment: Turned out that interpolating this did not work.Removing the quortes fixed the issue

Answer (score 11):

Change the permission of templates_c directory.

Comment: To be exact you need to allow write permissions for all users: use "chmod 777 filename"

Comment: ch MOD mod mod mod  - not chown or any other ch. . . . . . . . . . . .

Answer (score 4):

Give folder permission to folder smarty/template_c.

### I using Mac so follow this steps:

- Open Terminal
- Go to htdocs folder
- Go to project
- Go to Smarty lib
- Use command

  ```
   "chmod -R 0777 template_c"
  ```

My project is exists on the folder

```
    naveenos-MacBook-Pro:smarty nos$ chmod -R 0777 /Application/XAMPP/htdocs/smartyProject/lib/smarty/templates_c/
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding error checking to you page

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL + E_NOTICE);
```

If that gets you nothing, I would try setting the `$smarty->config_dir` and `$smarty->cache_dir` attributes. They might be needed.

And, of course, make sure the file permissions for all the directories are valid, and that SAFE_MODE is off. *(That can mess Smarty up in very odd ways.)*