# smarty changes makes a blank page

Tags: php, smarty

the admin panel of my website is created in smarty,If I made even an alphabet change in home.tpl and save it then upon logging into admin panel it shows me a blank screen.i am completly unaware what could be the reason behind it.Anyone who had experinced it before?
help will be appreciated
I believe there is no programming error but there are some view issues may be

Comment: Enable `display_errors` in `php.ini` then load the page again. The error will show up.

Comment: How many bytes is your template?  What version of Smarty?

Comment: @Shiplu there are no errors,i mean the control reaches to home.tpl but doesnt show its content

Comment: Solution posted on same type of question [Smarty outputs blank page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932556/smarty-outputs-blank-page/39749444#39749444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall template and make sure that at the end of tpl files there is no balnk space

Answer (score 1):

Dumb question: is the configuration right? You must also be sure that the application can display the template and not another.

Try writting {debug} in your template. It gives you all the parameters that you send to Smarty.

Another test -> make an "echo" at the method $smarty->display('home.tpl'); if you get a '1', it's ok, if not... you know.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of templates_c folder